# How to send logs to Zabbix from Dokku?

Tags: zabbix, dokku

I would like to use Dokku for deploying my Rails apps. But I cannot find any method allows me to send the log to Zabbix? Does anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't send logs directly to Zabbix for it's not a log collector.

You need a Zabbix Agent installed to your app machine to analyze logs and trigger events or, if you are using a PaaS, you should implement [web scenarios](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/web_monitoring#configuring_a_web_scenario) on your Zabbix Server to check specific URLs.

If you want to collect logs instead, you could implement a [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack).
Elastic search has its own alerting module but it's paid and IMHO Zabbix alerting is far better.